# C++ Program to Display Numbers Between Two Intervals Check Whether a Number can be Express as Sum of Two Prime Numbers

Tags: c++

i wrote a  Program to Display Numbers Between Two Intervals and Check Whether can be Express as Sum of Two Prime Numbers

This is my code

```
//============================================================================================
// Check whether and display a number between two intervals can be expressed as 2 prime number                                                           
//============================================================================================
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int checkPrime (int);
int main()
{
    int n1 , n2 , i , j;
    bool flag = false;
    cout << "Enter two number to check:" << endl;
    cin >> n1 >> n2 ;
    for (i = n1 ; i <= n2 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2 ; j <= i/2 ; j++ )
        {
            if(checkPrime (j) && checkPrime (i-j))
            {
                cout << "Number " << i << " equal sum of two prime number " << j << " + " << i - j << endl;
                flag = true;
            }                       
        }
        if (flag == false)
            {
                cout << "Number " << i << " can't epress to sum of two prime number " << endl;
            }
    }           
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

int checkPrime (int n)
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;          
        }       
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Out put
Enter two number to check:
1
12

```
Number 1 can't epress to sum of two prime number                                                                                                                                                          
Number 2 can't epress to sum of two prime number                                                                                                                                                          
Number 3 can't epress to sum of two prime number                                                                                                                                                          
Number 4 equal sum of two prime number 2 + 2                                                                                                                                                              
Number 5 equal sum of two prime number 2 + 3                                                                                                                                                              
Number 6 equal sum of two prime number 3 + 3                                                                                                                                                              
Number 7 equal sum of two prime number 2 + 5                                                                                                                                                              
Number 8 equal sum of two prime number 3 + 5                                                                                                                                                              
Number 9 equal sum of two prime number 2 + 7                                                                                                                                                              
Number 10 equal sum of two prime number 3 + 7                                                                                                                                                             
Number 10 equal sum of two prime number 5 + 5                                                                                                                                                             
Number 12 equal sum of two prime number 5 + 7
```

Number 11 is missing :-s and i dont know why :( pls help me to fix it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please keep the question title a short summary of the question.

Comment: I also recommend you read [this Stack Overflow checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons for negative votes. Lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset your flag at each loop otherwise once it's set with `true` value, this condition will never be reached `if (flag == false)`.

```
for (i = n1 ; i <= n2 ; i++)
{
    flag = false; /* Reset the flag */
    for (j = 2 ; j <= i/2 ; j++ )
    {
        if(checkPrime (j) && checkPrime (i-j))
        {
            cout << "Number " << i << " equal sum of two prime number " << j << " + " << i - j << endl;
            flag = true;
        }                       
    }
    if (flag == false)
    {
        cout << "Number " << i << " can't epress to sum of two prime number " << endl;
    }
}
```